# Android Maps Pinning a map overlay to coordinates

Tags: android, dictionary, bitmap, coordinates

Hi Im working on some code for college and I have thus far created a simple Google Map with the function of going to the users location, zooming in and out. I want to place a simple map drawing over a specific location on my map. 
I have done so much research but cannot seem to find the right way to do it. I tried to convert the coordinates of the location to pixels and place it here as a bitmap. The image won't stay where I position it. 
What I want to do basically is pin this image to the specific location and as the user zooms in and out, the image should shrink and stretch, essentially staying pinned to the exact location. 
I also can't seem to work out the drawBitmap() method, I want to have four positions, 
x, y, x-(image.width), y-(image.heigth) to position the image correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm not the strongest code and at my wits end.

Comment: I'm assuming you have looked at [Overlays](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) if not it might help, I would think an Itemized Overlay is what you would need....maybe.

Answer (score 0):

This library should help you out. It is fairly easy to include.
https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons